# using ResultSet select 10M record and dump onto HDFS

Tags: sql, performance, jdbc

In one program I did something like:

```
ResultSet rs = con.executeQuery(sql);
List l = new List();
while(rs.next()){
   l.append(rs.getObject(xxx))
}

fileSys.write(l)
```

the sql have 10M record. and this function takes 2hrs to finish. The Loop takes most of the time. I'm wondering is there a better way to do this thing? Is it possible to use multithread?

Comment: Why do you need to load 10M items into a list? Why don't you just output them directly to the file (assuming from your example that's what you want to do). If you're doing something else with a 10M item list, please clarify what it is.

Comment: write 10M item directly to a file is slower than append 10M item in a list and then write the whole list to file.

Comment: Ok, then try looking for a method that efficiently writes sql result sets to a file. A quick search found [THIS ARTICLE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ce36ce2c-5a7d-4c72-b3f2-574e2f1d8199/sql-query-output-to-a-text-file?forum=sqlgetstarted), but there are plenty of other possible ways to accomplish it, if that's all you're trying to do.

Comment: Here's another link - [THIS ONE FOR JAVA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364472/output-sql-query-results-to-flat-file-with-java). At some level, you must consider that you are transferring a lot of data to disk, and that *will* take some time, but 2 hrs seems overboard. Not sure if multithreading would even work - how would multiple threads write to the same file stream concurrently?

Comment: @SlimsGhost if the 2 hours is too much then there might be serious problem inside the SQL query. It may take too long for the server to prepare the query plan, execute it and if there were ~500 Bytes per record then it has to transfer ~5GB of data to the client. Without seeing the SQL I don't see any universal help other then make sure you have turned-off client's memory caching and you use fast ODBC forward-only cursor

Comment: @xmojmr I did a cpu profiler. Most of the time is used by network.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to move huge amount of data (Giga Bytes) over the network from one system (SQL) to another (HDFS) then threading in the processor driving the copying (your code) will not help much

**1** You can try to run your code on a server with better [network throughput](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measuring_network_throughput)

**2** You can try to copy only the records that had changed since the last time (HDFS does not have the copy yet). This would improve the performance in the long run. 1st time it would be slow. 2nd and 3rd time it would be faster as you'd only move things that had changed. Using UTC timestamps and "changed since" are the basic concepts